# New is taking lots of extra memory

Tags: c++, memory, new-operator

I'm making an application that is going to be using many dynamically created objects (raytracing). Instead of just using [new] over and over again, I thought I'd just make a simple memory system to speed things up. Its very simple at this point, as I don't need much.

My question is: when I run this test application, using my memory manager uses the correct amount of memory. But when I run the same loop using [new], it uses 2.5 to 3 times more memory. Is there just something I'm not seeing here, or does [new] incur a huge overhead?

I am using VS 2010 on Win7. Also I'm just using the Task Manager to view the process memory usage.

```
template<typename CLASS_TYPE>
class MemFact
{
public:
  int m_obj_size; //size of the incoming object
  int m_num_objs; //number of instances
  char* m_mem; //memory block

  MemFact(int num) : m_num_objs(num)
  {
    CLASS_TYPE t;
    m_obj_size = sizeof(t);
    m_mem = new char[m_obj_size * m_num_objs);
  }

  CLASS_TYPE* getInstance(int ID)
  {
    if( ID >= m_num_objs) return 0;
    return (CLASS_TYPE*)(m_mem + (ID * m_obj_size));
  }

  void release() { delete m_mem; m_mem = 0; }
};
/*---------------------------------------------------*/
class test_class
{
  float a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j; //10 floats
};
/*---------------------------------------------------*/
int main()
{
  int num = 10 000 000; //10 M items
  // at this point we are using 400K memory
  MemFact<test_class> mem_fact(num);
  // now we're using 382MB memory
  for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
     test_class* new_test = mem_fact.getInstance(i);
  mem_fact.release();
  // back down to 400K
  for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
     test_class* new_test = new test_class();
  // now we are up to 972MB memory
}
```

Comment: Your program is incomplete. We probably don't want it all anyway.

Comment: Sorry. I was trying to edit out the epic formatting fail but someone edited before me and locked out my changes I guess. It didn't like the way I put it in there

Comment: Is it perhaps in debug mode, where someone is tracking 10 million allocations?

Comment: It was in debug mode. I didn't know that added that much overhead. Building it in release mode brought it down to 600 MB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a minimum size for a memory allocation, depending on the CRT you are using. Often that's 16 bytes. Your object is 12 bytes wide (assuming x86), so you're probably wasting at least 4 bytes per allocation right there. The memory manager also has it's own structures to keep track of what memory is free and what memory is not -- that's not free. Your memory manager is probably much simplier (e.g. frees all those objects in one go) which is inherently going to be more efficient than what new does for the general case.

Also keep in mind that if you're building in debug mode, the debugging allocator will pad both sides of the returned allocation with canaries in an attempt to detect undefined behavior. That'll probably put you over the 16 byte boundary and into the next one -- probably a 32 byte allocation, at least. That'll be disabled when you build in release mode.

Answer (score -2):

Boy, I sure hope that nobody wants to allocate any non-PODs from your memory manager. Or objects of dynamic size. And doesn't mind instantiating it for every type. Or creating as many as they like all at once. Or having their lifetime be longer than the `MemFact`.

In fact, there *is* a valid pattern known as an Object Pool, which is similar to yours but doesn't suck. The simple answer is that `operator new` is required to be ultra flexible- it's objects must live forever until `delete` is called- and their destructor must be called too, and they must all have completely separate, independent lifetimes. It must be able to allocate variable-size objects, and of any type, at any time. Your `MemFact` meets none of these requirements. The Object Pool also has less requirements, and *is* significantly faster than regular `new` because of it, but it also doesn't completely fail on all the other fronts.

You're trying to compare an almost completely rotten apple with an orange.

Comment: I said... It doesn't need to be flexible. I'm using it for 2 simple classes where they exist as long as the MemFact does. I was asking about [new]... not my class. No need to be rude.